# Unable to access methods which i have created on other Class

Tags: java

I have created 2 classes and I am trying to access the methods from other class by creating an object and trying to call the method, but I am not able to.

**Class 1**

```
public class Paramdemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Paramdemo obj1=new Paramdemo();
        obj1.sub();
        obj2.sum();
    }   
  }     
}
```

**Class 2**

```
public class Paramdemo2 {
    public int  sum (int a, int b) {
        int c = a + b;
        return c;
    }

    public double sum(double d, double f) {
        double a = d + f;
        System.out.println("Print " + z);
        return a;
    }

    public  int sub(int c, int d) {
        int z = c + d;
        return z;       
    }
}
```

Comment: On main Class I am not able to access the methods, If i create methods in the main class I am able to access it.

Comment: `sub()` and `sum()` are methods of `Paramdemo2`, but you create a `Paramdemo` object which has no methods.

Comment: You are creating an object of the class Paramdemo not of the class Paramdemo2 which contains the methods.

Comment: the 2 things i see, there is no `obj2` defined, and `sub(int,int)` is what you need to call not `sub()`

Comment: This is not really usefull, a [mcve] would have been useful as this is not verifiable. But since there are typos, this will sovle your problem. I have voted to closed it already.

Comment: Just a quick reminder: please check if one of the answers you got is helpful enough for you to accept it. If not, please let me know if I can add something to make it acceptable.

Comment: @GhostCat Hai now i m fine now ,Thanks to all

Answer (score 2):

Here:

```
Paramdemo obj1=new Paramdemo();
```

but `Parademo` doesn't have those methods you intend to invoke; `Parademo2` has them!

Simple as that - just change the type of `obj1`!

And then add the definition for obj2, or rename it to obj1. And finally: include the required parameters for the methods.

Answer (score 1):

You are not able to call these methods because you are creating object of **Paramdemo** class itselt and **Paramdemo** class doesn't contain any method. You have to create object of **Paramdemo2** class.

```
Paramdemo2 obj1 = new Paramdemo2();
obj1.sub(10, 5);
obj1.sum(10, 4);
```